# Common data between js modules in IE8

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer-8

I have a web app made of several jsp files, several of which make use of common jscript modules. My problem is that I am having difficulties accessing common data between the jscript modules in IE8.

For example - In a jsp file:

```
<script for="window" event="onload">
// My globals.
myGlobals = new Object();
// Attach it to the window for maximum availability.
window.myGlobals = myGlobals;
// Add some fields to it.
// List is actually built from external data so cannot be included from external file.
myGlobals.filters = [
'Filter-Women',
'Filter-Men',
'Filter-Girls',
'Filter-Boys',
];
myGlobals.filtered = '';
</script>
```

and in a separate js file:

```
function filter(f) {
  for (var i = 0;i < myGlobals.filters.length;i++){
    if ( 'Filter-'+f == myGlobals.filters[i] ) {
      filterIn(document.getElementById(myGlobals.filters[i]));
    } else {
      filterOut(document.getElementById(myGlobals.filters[i]));
    }
  }
  myGlobals.filtered = f;
}

function filterIn(e) {
  e.classList.add('filterselected');
}

function filterOut(e) {
  e.classList.remove('filterselected');
}
```

and in my jsp - the list is also built from the same external data as above:

```
<div class="filterbuttons">
<a id="Filter-Women" onclick="filter('Women')">WOMEN</a>
<a id="Filter-Men" onclick="filter('Men')">MEN</a>
<a id="Filter-Girls" onclick="filter('Girls')">GIRLS</a>
<a id="Filter-Boys" onclick="filter('Boys')">BOYS</a>
</div>
```

Now this all works fine in Firefox but customer also needs this to work in IE8. There, the myGlobals structure is not available, not even from the window. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

Change:

```
<script for="window" event="onload">
```

to just plain:

```
<script>
```

and everything works fine again.